# Django: Implementing fund reversal in post_save signal

Tags: python, django, django-signals, banking

I'm using django `post_save` signal to update the `status` of a transaction based on whether funds are received. The problem is that `funds_received` is not working as expected. The issue is in using `.exists()`, because, it checks if there is any account with the exact balance equal to the transaction amount. If anyone has suggestions or knows of a better way for checking if funds are received, I would greatly appreciate the guidance.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Transaction, Account

@receiver(post_save, sender=Transaction)
def transaction_status(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        amount = instance.amount
        sender_account = instance.sender.account
        receiver_account_number = instance.account_number
        receiver_account = account.objects.get(account_number=receiver_account_number)

        check_if_funds_received = Account.objects.filter(account_balance=amount).exists()

        funds_received = check_if_funds_received

        if funds_received:
            instance.status = 'Success'
            instance.save()
        else:
            instance.status = 'Reversed'
            instance.save()
            # return funds to sender
            sender_account.account_balance += amount
            sender_account.save()
```

**My Models**:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account_number = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    account_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=6)
    account_id = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    user_qrcode = models.ImageField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    account_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ACCOUNT_STATUS)
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.first_name)


class Transaction(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Success', 'Success'),
        ('Reversed', 'Reversed')
    )
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receiver')
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=6)
    account_number = models.BigIntegerField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATUS)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=reference_number, unique=True)
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=4)
```

```
    views.py
from decimal import Decimal
from django.contrib import messages

def create_transfer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        amount = Decimal(request.POST.get('amount'))
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        pin = request.POST.get('pin')

        sender_account = Account.objects.get(user=request.user)  
        receiver_account = Account.objects.get(account_number=request.POST.get('account_number'))

        if sender_account.account_balance >= amount:
            sender_account.account_balance -= amount
            sender_account.save()

            receiver_account.account_balance += amount
            receiver_account.save()

            Transaction.objects.create(
                sender=sender_account.user, 
                receiver=receiver_account.user,
                amount=amount,
                pin=pin, 
                first_name=receiver_account.first_name, 
                last_name=receiver_account.last_name,
                account_number=receiver_account
            )
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Insufficient Funds')
            return redirect('Transaction')
    return render(request, 'create_transfer.html')
```

Comment: What is the scenario in which transaction is finished, but funds are not delivered?

Comment: @BartoszStasiak check the question again.

Answer (score 0):

IMO your solution to this issue is wrong in the first place.

In your case the transaction is considered successful, because account balance was updated. But it should be other way around.

Balance should be updated, because transaction was successful.

You can even implement balance as a property of a Account. It will be calculated on the fly based on the sum of successful Transactions to this account.

Your Transaction model fields receiver and sender should also point to Account instead of the User profile. It will be much simpler to link it to correct account. Account already has FK to User

Here is simplified case. I think it will be a good way to start from this

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False, blank=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name="received_transactions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name="sent_transactions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Account(models.Model):
    @property
    def account_balance(self):
        debit_balance = self.received_transactions.filter(status=SUCCESS).aggregate(debit=Sum("amount", default=0))["debit"]
        credit_balance = self.sent_transactions.filter(status=SUCCESS).aggregate(credit=Sum("amount", default=0))["credit"]

        return debit_balance - credit_balance
```

Comment: This might not be sufficient for a real-world scenario. My implementation provides a clearer representation of an Account model. Using sender and receiver as user fields in the Transaction model means you can directly reference the users, simplifying the retrieval process. You can easily filter transactions based on the sender or receiver, facilitating queries related to a particular user's transaction history, such as who initiated the transaction and who received it.

Comment: Sometimes, you may send the funds, but the receiver doesn't receive them, while the sender gets deducted.

Comment: This is definitely sufficient. Many companies, including my current one do this with great success. Read about ledger entries. I would say your implementation is not clear and complicated and it shows in your question. Transactions deduct or add funds to Account, but there is no clear relation between account and transaction. (Bad schema design). Both account and transactions have reference to user (redundancy, no single source of truth, potential data corruption). I also don't understand your point. Account has reference to User already so you can filter accounts and transactions by the user.

Comment: In my example there is one source of truth who is the owner of the account and receiver/sender of the transaction. (User on the Account). There will never be an issue that balance is incorrect (Because it's based on successful transactions.  It will always be right and up to date). You can also clearly see fro which account to which money was transferred and there is even potential for user to have multiple accounts in the future. In your case there could be a case that balance will not match sum of credits and debits on the transactions, because it independent of Transactions etc etc